# Twitter Bootstrap Extend Background Across Screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, haml

Would like the "light grey" background (on http://CappedIn.com) across the top navigation to stretch across the whole screen. The rest of the content I would like as is. Any ideas how to do this? HAML code include (it shows bootstrap classes I use)

```
%body
  %div.container-fluid
    %div.row-fluid.top_nav
      %div.span7
        = render "/shared/navigation/top_left_nav.html.haml"         
      %div.span5
        = render "/shared/navigation/top_right_nav.html.haml"
    = yield
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS -

```
.top_nav {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    width: auto;
    background: #EEEEEE;
}
```